# Incrementing a counter for dateadd

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I'm trying to increase the time between dates by a set amount.  For example, I want to add two months to the time between date 1,2 and 3.  I'm having trouble incrementing my 'date counter'...

```
DECLARE @monthDiff int

SET @monthDiff = 1;

UPDATE [Table1]
SET [Date] = DATEADD(MONTH, (SET @monthDiff = @monthDiff + 1), [Date])
WHERE [ID] IN 
(
    SELECT [ID]
    FROM [Table2]
    WHERE [Description] = 'HE'
);
```

An example might help...

Original dates:

```
01/04/1984
01/05/1984
01/06/1984
```

New dates:

```
01/04/1984
01/06/1984
01/08/1984
```

Any ideas?

I'm using SQLServer 2005.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do here, generally a WHILE @monthDiff < 3 BEGIN ..DATEADD CODE HERE... END will work to increment

Comment: An example might help...

Original dates: 01/04/1984, 01/05/1984, 01/06/1984
New dates: 01/04/1984, 01/06/1984, 01/08/1984

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
;WITH cte AS
(
SELECT t1.ID, 
       t1.[Date], 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.ID ORDER BY [Date]) AS RN
FROM Table1 t1
JOIN Table2 t2
ON t1.ID = t2.ID 
WHERE t2.[Description] = 'HE'
)
UPDATE CTE
SET [Date] = DATEADD(MONTH, RN-1, [Date])
```

Comment: This is almost what I need except that I need the 'RowNumber' to 'reset' for each ID.  For example... [Date] 01/04/1984 [ID] 1 [RN] 1, [Date] 01/05/1984 [ID] 1 [RN] 2, [Date] 01/06/1984 [ID] 1 [RN] 3.  Followed by [Date] 01/10/1984 [ID] 2 [RN] 1, [Date] 01/11/1984 [ID] 2 [RN] 2, [Date] 01/12/1984 [ID] 2 [RN] 3

Comment: @paulio - See Edit. You can reset the row number by using `PARTITION BY [ID]`

Answer (score 0):

this should work, although only if each original date in your table is unique. I've called the column mydate because I don't think date is a legal (or sensible) name for a column. This could be easier and safer if you've got some kind of ID column. then we would use that for the cursor rather than the date

```
declare @numberOfMonthsToAdd int
declare @currentDate dateTime
set @numberOfMonthsToAdd = 0
declare myCursor cursor  for 
select [mydate] from Table1
open myCursor
while @@fetch_Status<>-1
begin
fetch next from myCursor into @currentDate
update Table1 set [mydate] = DATEADD(month,@numberOfMonthsToAdd, [mydate]) where [mydate] = @currentDate
set @numberOfMonthsToAdd = @numberOfMonthsToAdd + 1

end
close mycursor
deallocate mycursor
```

Answer (score 0):

From your example, it seems you want to change the dates relative to a base date:

```
declare @basedate datetime
select @basedate = min([Date]) FROM Table1 WHERE ...

UPDATE [Table1]
SET [Date] = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, @basedate, [Date]) * 2, [Date])
WHERE ...
```